# ServiceStack.UseCases self hosting failure

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mono, servicestack

I am trying to take the github ServiceStack.UseCases/ImageResizer project, and make it self hosted. I thought this would be really easy, so I referenced this: https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/Self-hosting but AppSelfHostBase is undefined in the project.  I then tried AppHostHttpListenerBase and that got me to the point where I could at least hope to setup my self host:

```
public class AppHost : AppHostHttpListenerBase  
{
    public AppHost() : base("Image Resizer", typeof(AppHost).Assembly) {}
    public override void Configure(Container container) {}
}

public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        AppHost appHost = new AppHost();
        appHost.Init();
        appHost.Start("http://*:1301/");
    }
}
```

I then transferred the project over to my CentOS box with mono.  In monodevelop I was able to build and run, but it failed during runtime.  It appears it still thinks it is an Mvc or Asp.Net project.

Aside from this attempt, I have a working self hosted ServiceStack project running there, but it is not this ImageResizer and all attempts to get my existing project to include the new project have also failed.

I also tried to include code that was part of the working self hosted project into the new one, but then symbols are undefined.  Basic symbols like "ServiceStackHost".  If I start trying to use Nuget and do more "Install-Package" I can solve this symbol problem, but then just cause other symbols that used to be resolved to no longer work.  I don't really fully understand Nuget.  Any ideas for a way forward would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ServiceStackHost` and `AppSelfHostBase` are new classes added in **ServiceStack v4**.

You can use `AppHostHttpListenerBase` which is a Self-hosting class in **ServiceStack v3**. You're looking at the `v4` docs, here are the [docs for ServiceStack v3](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki) which for [Self-Hosting](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Self-hosting) is at:

https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/wiki/Self-hosting

Self-Hosting apps are normally created in a **Console Application** where-as your example is trying to run a self-hosting app inside an **ASP.NET Web Application**. If you want to run ServiceStack in an ASP.NET app you should inherit `AppHostBase`, otherwise if you want to run a self-hosting application, create a new **Console Application** and inherit from `AppHostHttpListenerBase`.

Comment: The part that is confusing to sort out is what versions of projects are being downloaded from Nuget vs. what is in Github.  I cloned what was in Github for the ServiceStack.UseCases/ImageResizer and I just built that with no changes.  I guess my mistake was to think that the latest ServiceStack.UseCases was a later version.  So then if I find documentation for 4.0 or later for ServiceStack I can't expect it to work with even a fresh Github download of a project built with ServiceStack.  - Thats what it really comes down to.  Github has all kinds of various versions, not always the latest.Thx.

Comment: @tradetree All [ServiceStack Apps](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps) and [Live Demos](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/LiveDemos) have been upgraded to v4. You can find some [v3 Examples in v3 branches](https://github.com/ServiceStackV3/ServiceStackV3/blob/master/README.md#source-code-for-v3).